# Publish PowerBI Report Builder Reports to a SQL SSRS server

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, reportbuilder

I have recently downloaded the PowerBI 'Report Builder' app. Following File -> Publish, I only get the PowerBI service available to publish to. I do believe that previously I was also allowed to publish to a SQL Server SSRS instance in a similar way as to how you do it in Visual Studio SSDT Reporting Services. I can't find any options to turn this feature on - does anyone know if this has been removed or can be switched on. Any help very much appreciated.

I have tried locating how to do this in the app. On a Google search people speak of the ability to publish reporting parts and to choose this option in Files -> Publish, but this option does not exist for me..

Comment: I don't user Power BI but it appears there is "Microsoft Power BI Report Builder" https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=58158 and then the SSRS version "Microsoft Report Builder" https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53613 . It maybe the the PB version can also publish to SSRS but the description says "optimized for authoring paginated reports for the Power BI service".